# Google Compute Engine stopped reporting CPU usage

Tags: google-compute-engine

It stopped reporting since June 28th, after midday.

Anyone knows why? Only changes made in the system were automatic system updates.

[image: CPU usage]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a bug fix we rolled out in late June:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/release-notes#june2016

Lower and less noisy usage is expected, especially for mostly-idle VMs, but if the graph remains flat even if the VM is busy, it's possible we have broken something.

Comment: After some experimenting, it appears that our previous bug fix did indeed introduce this bug. It gets triggered by an in-guest reboot (e.g., "sudo shutdown -r now"). We'll have a fix rolled out next week or the week after. In the meantime, the in-guest metrics remain accurate and using stop->start to reboot instances works around the problem. Apologies and thanks for reporting this Juan.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that `gcloud compute instances stop my-instance` `gcloud compute instances start my-instance` brings back CPU reporting.

Comment: Now, CPU reporting has returned to life in my machine, without need to stop, start nor reboot.

Comment: The correct answer is the first comment of this answer, not the answer itself. I don't know how to mark it.